# How do I use JCIFS with apache VFS to access an SMB URL?

Tags: java, apache, smb, jcifs, apache-commons-vfs

I am trying to access a folder on my local computer using an smb URL.
my project is using the jars: commons-vfs2-2.0.jar and jcifs-1.3.17.jar (and all the other required jars).
The code in it's entirety is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileSystemException {
    jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler();
    StaticUserAuthenticator auth = new StaticUserAuthenticator(<domain>,<user>,<password>);
    FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions(); 
    DefaultFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserAuthenticator(opts, auth);
    FileSystemManager fs = VFS.getManager();
    FileObject smbFile = fs.resolveFile("smb://10.0.2.2/TimeOut/");
    System.out.println(smbFile.exists() + " " + smbFile.getContent().getLastModifiedTime());
}
```

I am receiving the exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not determine the
>   type of file "smb://10.0.2.2/TimeOut".    at
>   org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getType(AbstractFileObject.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.exists(AbstractFileObject.java:477)
>     at com.newsway.tests.VfsTest.main(VfsTest.java:23) Caused by:
>   jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: account currently disabled.
>     at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:546)    at
>   jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:663)    at
>   jcifs.smb.SmbSession.sessionSetup(SmbSession.java:390)    at
>   jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:218)    at
>   jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:176)   at
>   jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doConnect(SmbFile.java:911)     at
>   jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:954)   at
>   jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)  at
>   jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:972)     at
>   jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:1006)     at
>   jcifs.smb.SmbFileInputStream.(SmbFileInputStream.java:73)   at
>   jcifs.smb.SmbFileInputStream.(SmbFileInputStream.java:65)   at
>   jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getInputStream(SmbFile.java:2844)   at
>   org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.url.UrlFileObject.doGetType(UrlFileObject.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getType(AbstractFileObject.java:496)

from which I understand that the relevant part is: *Logon failure: account currently disabled.*

This is despite the fact that my user/password/domain are fine and I am doing exactly what is defined in the VFS documentation page.

What am I missing?

Comment: Problem solved. I was missing the VFS sandbox jar

Comment: I had the same issue. When I included VFS sandbox 2.1-SNAPSHOT I now get a different exception. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779254/how-do-i-use-jcifs-with-apache-vfs-to-access-an-smb-url-part-2

Comment: The `jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler();` looks wrong. It seems it uses the URL handler instead of the jcifs provider. Can you add `System.out.println("prov? " + fs.hasProvider("smb"));` after getManager()?

Comment: Using the commons-vfs-sandbox-2.1-SNAPSHOT the System.out.println(fs.hasProvider("smb")); prints true. It seems that the right provider is loaded successfully.

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what your problem is, the sandbox providers are not registered automatically in 2.0. And also you need to actually use the configured authentication properties in the resolve call (see modified source below).

I typically not use the default filesystem manager but register my providers dynamically, but if you want to use the automatic detection, you need to add vfs-providers.xml to the sandbox JAR.

This is how you build a complete working JAR with 2.0:

```
> git clone https://github.com/apache/commons-vfs.git -b commons-vfs2-project-2.0 vfs2.0
> cd vfs2.0
> notepad sandbox\pom.xml
> notepad sandbox\src\test\java\org\apache\commons\vfs2\provider\smb\test\StandaloneMain.java
> mvn -Pinclude-sandbox -DskipTests=true clean package dependency:tree
```

When you edit the sandbox/pom.xml, you need to make sure to remove -SANDBOX from <version> and <parent><version> tags. Then you need to add:

```
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
```

to the already existing <resources> tag (right after first LICENSE+NOTICE include line 88)

This is the test code used:

```
package org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.smb.test;

import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemManager;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemOptions;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.VFS;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.auth.StaticUserAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemConfigBuilder;


public class StandaloneMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileSystemException {
        //jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler();
        StaticUserAuthenticator auth = 
              new StaticUserAuthenticator("DOMAIN", "user", "SECRET");
        FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();
        DefaultFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserAuthenticator(opts, auth);
        FileSystemManager fs = VFS.getManager();
        if (!fs.hasProvider("smb")) throw new RuntimeException("Provider missing");
        System.out.println("Connecting " + args[0] + " with " + opts);
        FileObject smbFile = fs.resolveFile(args[0], opts); // added opts!
        System.out.println(smbFile.exists() + " " + smbFile.getContent().getLastModifiedTime());
    }
}
```

And this is the execution:

```
> set REP=C:\Users\USERNAME\.m2\repository
> java -cp sandbox\target\commons-vfs2-sandbox-2.0.jar;^
           core\target\commons-vfs2-2.0.jar;^
           %REP%\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;^
           %REP%\jcifs\jcifs\0.8.3\jcifs-0.8.3.jar;^
           sandbox\target\test-classes
       org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.smb.test.StandaloneMain smb://HOST/Users
Jan 05, 2015 2:40:19 PM org.apache.commons.vfs2.VfsLog info
INFORMATION: Using "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\vfs_cache" as temporary files store.
Connecting smb://eckenfels02/Users with org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemOptions@27dd2ec5
true 0
```

Comment: I just commited a fix for the missing vfs-provider.xml (VFS-552) to trunk, it will be in 2.1

Answer (score -1):

I use different authentication method and it works, you may give it a shot.

```
String url = "smb://10.0.2.2/TimeOut/";   
NtlmPasswordAuthentication authen = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(<domain>,<username>,<password>); 
SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(url,authen);
```

Comment: The question was about using commons vfs to perform SMB operations, not the pure JCIFS api