# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.FileProvider

Tags: java, tomcat, samba, vfs, apache-commons-vfs

I'm using the vfs2 (not vfs) to access ftp. Now I also use the smb protocol but it does not work. 
I always get the Exception:

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.FileProvider
```

But as I'm using vfs2 it is weird that it searches for classes with commons.vfs.provider and not commons.vfs2.provider - because in vfs2 the class exists.

Do I miss a library (jar)?

I have at the moment: `commons-vfs2-2.0.jar`, `commons-vfs2-sandbox-2.0.jar` (had to be added to find smb protocol), `jcifs-1.3.17.jar`, `commons-net-3.3.jar`, `commons-collections-3.2.1.jar`, `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar` and may more..

Here my complete StackTrace:

```
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not create a file system manager of class "org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.StandardFileSystemManager".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.VFS.createManager(VFS.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.VFS.getManager(VFS.java:50)
    at com.avintis.framework.service.DbAccessImpl.saveArchiveData(DbAccessImpl.java:1188)
    at com.avintis.framework.service.DbAccessImpl.saveMessageData(DbAccessImpl.java:905)
    at com.avintis.framework.service.DbAccessImpl.saveMessage(DbAccessImpl.java:417)
    at com.avintis.framework.service.ImportTrackingMsgServiceImpl.importFile(ImportTrackingMsgServiceImpl.java:77)
    at com.avintis.framework.service.ImportTrackingMsgServiceImpl.importFile(ImportTrackingMsgServiceImpl.java:30)
    at com.avintis.framework.watcher.service.WatcherServiceImpl.addTrackingMessages(WatcherServiceImpl.java:87)
    at com.avintis.framework.watcher.service.WatcherServiceImpl.watchForFiles(WatcherServiceImpl.java:34)
    at com.avintis.framework.schedule.WatcherJob.executeInternal(WatcherJob.java:30)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:534)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/vfs/provider/FileProvider
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.StandardFileSystemManager.createInstance(StandardFileSystemManager.java:485)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.StandardFileSystemManager.addProvider(StandardFileSystemManager.java:371)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.StandardFileSystemManager.configure(StandardFileSystemManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.StandardFileSystemManager.configure(StandardFileSystemManager.java:195)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.StandardFileSystemManager.configurePlugins(StandardFileSystemManager.java:154)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.StandardFileSystemManager.init(StandardFileSystemManager.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.VFS.createManager(VFS.java:88)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.FileProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first sight it looks like you need the `commons-vfs.jar` not the `commons-vfs2-2.0.jar` because the packagename in `commons-vfs2-2.0.jar` is `org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.jar`. But this may cause problems with mixing up vfs and vfs2 classes and not work.

So make sure you have following jars (only vfs2) loaded:

- commons-vfs2-2.0.jar
- commons-vfs2-sandbox-2.0.jar
- jcifs-1.3.17.jar
- And other [depending commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/download.html) (net, logging,...)

Then also add the `vfs-providers.xml` inside your `META-INF` pointing to the correct class for the SmbFileProvider:

```
<provider class-name="org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.smb.SmbFileProvider">
    <scheme name="smb"/>
    <if-available class-name="jcifs.smb.SmbFile"/>
</provider>
```

Comment: This gives the next Exception: `org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.smb.SmbFileProvider cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.FileProvider`. Somewhere the vfs2 library is mixing up with the old vfs library

Comment: But where? I only have vfs2 libraries. As you can see in the above StackTrace - it is the vfs2 Loader that automatically tries to load a vfs class...

Comment: @FiveO Do you have also changed the sanbox.jar?

Comment: @FiveO It looks like the class wich is loaded comes from a configuration file. May you have a configuration problem. Where you configure it?

Comment: I haven't modified any jar (But the sandbox may be suspicious - the official site does not give a download). I don't have a configuration file (vfs-providers.xml) - it should take the default.

Comment: @FiveO What is the Default?

Comment: I don't know - this is what VFS2 is telling, but maybe smb is not in the defaults.. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/api.html

Comment: Do you have an example of the vfs-providers.xml with smb configuration?

Comment: @FiveO No sorry i havn't

Comment: Seems like all build of the vfs sandbox point to old classes. And the download of the sandbox on the apache commons vfs page is not available. I'm really stuck here - just save a file to a Windows Share...

Comment: You won't believe it! It worked! Had to add the sandbox-2.0 and add the provider with vfs2 in the vfs-providers.xml. I'll modify your answer and add these parts! Thanks for your great help - felt not alone with my problem ;-)

Comment: BTW: to build a VFS 2.0 sandbox jar with working vfs-provider.xml you can check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27780881/13189